# Embedding and iterating over custom faces in CGAL Delaunay triangulation

Tags: c++, cgal, triangulation, delaunay

I'm using the CGAL library for performing Delaunay triangulation in my C++ application. I would like to embed custom faces into the triangulation and then iterate over them, but I'm not sure how to incorporate them into the triangulation and how to iterate over the custom faces afterwards.

At the end I want something like this:

```cpp
  typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<EPIC> DelaunayTriangulation;
  DelaunayTriangulation triangulation;
  // ...
  for (auto it = triangulation.faces_begin(); it != triangulation.faces_end(); ++it)
  {
    MyFace& face = static_cast<MyFace&>(*it);
    // ...
  }
```

Can someone explain how I can embed my custom face into the Delaunay triangulation?

## Edit

As correctly pointed out in the comments, I actually want to extend the Face class used during Delaunay triangulation in CGAL to store additional information in the constructor for reuse.

Comment: Can't you create the triangles on the fly ? Or do you need to store additional properties for reuse?

Comment: A triangulation face is not the same thing as a triangle: a face is mostly combinatorial information (what are my vertices, what are my neighboring faces, etc.) whereas a triangle is just a triplet of 3D points. Do you want a custom geometrical triangle type, or do you want your combinatorial faces to store some specific information?

Comment: @Mael You are right. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short version:** have a look at [CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_with_info_2](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__face__base__with__info__2.html).

**Longer version below:**

Your triangulation expects its face type to provide it some specific API: if you check [the doc of CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Delaunay__triangulation__2.html), you can see it wants its face to be a model of the concept [TriangulationDataStructure_2::Face](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/TDS_2/classTriangulationDataStructure__2_1_1Face.html).

By default, CGAL will use `CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2` templated with `CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_2` as template classes that fit those requirements. You can enrich existing face base classes by deriving from `CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_2`. This is what is done for example in the class `CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_with_id_2`, which inherits `CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_2` and adds an ID member.

The class [CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_with_info_2](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__face__base__with__info__2.html) provides this in a generic way as you can pass whatever info you want as a template parameter (be it a bool or a class itself).

Since you are no longer using the default classes, you will need to specify the `CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2` templates:

```cpp
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<K> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_with_info_2<**YOUR_INFO_TYPE**,K> Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb,Fb> Tds;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,Tds> Triangulation;
```